# Ambiguous results when using AWK to print fields in a string separated out by regex delimiter

Tags: regex, awk

I am exploring the use of regular expressions as field separators in `awk`. I came up with the below example to split a string and print fields separated out by a regex delimiter `[ad]*`.

```
echo avadakedavra | awk -F '[ad]*' '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {print "["i"]"$i}}'
```

Below is the output I get while running this script on MobaXterm which runs AWK version `BusyBox v1.19.2`:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]
[4]k
[5]e
[6]
[7]v
[8]r
[9]
[10]
```

Whereas, I get the below output while running on my linux box with `GNU Awk 3.1.5`:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]ke
[4]vr
[5]
```

Is this difference in behavior a bug in one version or the other? If this is a bug, what output should I be expecting? If my understanding of regex is correct, the output returned by `BusyBox v1.19.2` is right. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there any alternate way of getting the same results reliably irrespective of the AWK version ?

**Edit #1**

With the delimiter `[ad]+` I am not expecting empty strings in the output as the delimiter pattern cannot evaluate to empty strings, but I still see them using both `gawk` and `busybox`.

```
echo avadakedavra | awk -F '[ad]+' '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {print "["i"]"$i}}'
```

Output on `gawk 3.1.5` is:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]ke
[4]vr
[5]
```

whereas output on `Busybox v1.19.2` is:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]ke
[4]vr
[5]vra
```

Similarly, I tried out a different regex `a[d]*` as the delimiter and the output on `gawk` is:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]
[4]ked
[5]vr
[6]
```

`BusyBox` responded with the below:

```
[1]
[2]v
[3]
[4]ked
[5]vr
[6]a
```

Comment: Do you know what `*` quantifier is for?  Did you mean `+`?

Comment: @karakfa - I am intentionally trying to use `*` to understand how it behaves. I did go through a quick regex tutorial to make sure my understanding is right.The quantifier `*` is for 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: Exactly! If there are zero matches what do you want to happen?  Perhaps you meant use "a" or "d" as delimiters.  Based on your output `gawk` is greedy (as almost all others) whereas BB is not.

Comment: Interesting problem, thanks for adding some interest to our day ;-) .... The "empty string" you mention causing you concern in Edit#1 is the same "empty string" you would get if you were using a more typical FS, like '|' and had an input string like `|fld2|fld3||fld5|`... So fld1,4,6 are empty, right? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - `BusyBox` does not even allow FS to be `|ad|a||d|`. It errors out with `awk: bad regex '|ad|a||d|': empty (sub)expression`. `gawk` does not complain though.

Comment: Sorry, typo. `FS="|"` . And please reread my comment. This is about one aspect of  your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - You are right - fld1,4,6 are empty in the example you mentioned. So it looks like I must be prepared to get empty fields in the output when using -F. Going by this logic `gawk` output in my Edit#1 looks correct but `BusyBox` is totally incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is perl-compatible re behaviour (the pattern first greedy matches the longest substring, then an empty one), the latter is not. For simplicity it is better use + instead of * in this case.

Comment: If I want to use `a[d]*` as delimiter, the results are still different on `gawk` and `BusyBox` for the versions I mentioned. I also tried `[ad]+` and the results are still different.